# Why throwing an exception tries to loads the class which extends Exception (though it is not executed) but not a regular class

Tags: java, java-8, jvm-hotspot

I have the below classes.

I have manually compiled the classes using **javac** and ran the `Driver` class.

Later **removed** the `entity.class` and `MyCustomException.class` and ran the app like below.

> java Driver test

The below error is complained about `MyCustomException` is missing but not about the `Entity` class.  So, not clear why JRE complaining about `MyCustomException` class but not the `Entity` class.

Indeed I have removed code `throw  new MyCustomException();` but I did not encounter error about `Entity` class.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/techdisqus/exception/MyCustomException
```

Please note that the **IF** condition will **NOT** be **executed** as I am passing command argument as **test**

Why is it throwing an exception is causing to load the `MyCustomException` which would be never executed but the JVM does not load any other regular class unless condition is satisfied, as here `Entity` class here. Please check `Driver.java` below.

MyCustomException.java

```
public class MyCustomException extends RuntimeException {

}
```

Entity.java

```
public class Entity {
}
```

Driver.java

```
public class Driver {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = args[0];
        if("true".equals(s)){
            Entity entity = new Entity(); // This is not loaded, unless s is true
            throw  new MyCustomException(); // this is loaded even s is NOT true.
        }else{
            System.out.println("success");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Thanks for help

Comment: Something to try: get rid of `Entity`, it just obscures things. Then see if there is a difference between the error messages you get when you `throw new MyCustomException()` and simply call `new MyCustomException()` without throwing.

Comment: @Arkadiy yes, it causes error while throw `MyCustomException`.. I think I would edit the question to make it clear.. and accepted answer answers this part.. I realised it has to do with throw not about creating object.

Comment: Yes indeed, please edit the question. The answer is great, it deserves the best question you can give it :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(this is an educated guess; I'm by no means an expert on JVM internals)

I assume the error happens during [verification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10), when the loaded class undergoes some sanity checks so the runtime can make some assumptions later.

One of the checks is a typecheck of bytecode instructions. Specifically [`athrow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.1.9.athrow):

> An athrow instruction is type safe iff the top of the operand stack matches Throwable.

So at this point, the classloader has to load `MyCustomException` to check whether it extends `Throwable`

Comment: Exactly. But it’s important to keep in mind that this is an implementation specific behavior and other JVMs may handle this differently.

Comment: @Holger you're probably right, but I don't see how the JVM spec I linked above leaves much wiggle room to avoid losing the exception class.

Comment: There’s some freedom regarding the point of verification. The HotSpot JVM does it when trying to enter the `main` method, but it could also do it earlier, when initializing the containing `Driver` class, or later, right before actually trying to execute the `athrow` instruction. On the other hand, the absence of the `Entity` class is only detected before actually trying to execute the `new` instruction, but another implementation could check this at method entry or even class initialization already.